# PHP make N copies of array with functions

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

In my code I need to make a number of copies of a dummy array. The array is simple, for example `$dummy = array('val'=> 0)`. I would like make N copies of this array and tack them on to the end of an existing array that has a similar structure. Obviously this could be done with a for loop but for readability, I'm wondering if there are any built in functions that would make this more verbose.

Here's the code I came up with using a for loop:

```
//example data, not real code
$existingArray = array([0] => array('val'=>2),[1] => array('val'=>3) );

$n = 2;
for($i=0;$i<$n;$i++) {
   $dummy = array('val'=>0); //make a new array
   $existingArray[] = $dummy; //add it to the end of $existingArray
}
```

To reiterate, I'd like to rewrite this with functions if such functions exist. Something along the lines of this (obviously these are not real functions):

```
//make $n copies of the array
$newvals = clone(array('val'=>0), $n);

//tack the new arrays on the end of the existing array
append($newvals, $existingArray)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're looking for [`array_fill`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill.php):

> ```
> array array_fill ( int $start_index , int $num , mixed $value )
> ```
>
> Fills an array with `num` entries of the value of the `value` parameter, keys starting at the `start_index` parameter.

So:

```
$newElements = array_fill(0, $n, Array('val' => 0));
```

You do still have to handle the appending of `$newElements` to `$existingArray` yourself, probably with [`array_merge`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php):

> ```
> array array_merge ( array $array1 [, array $... ] )
> ```
>
> Merges the elements of one or more arrays together so that the values of one are appended to the end of the previous one. It returns the resulting array.
>
> If the input arrays have the same string keys, then the later value for that key will overwrite the previous one. If, however, the arrays contain numeric keys, the later value will ***not*** overwrite the original value, but will be appended.
>
> Values in the input array with numeric keys will be renumbered with incrementing keys starting from zero in the result array.

So:

```
$existingArray = array_merge($existingArray, $newElements);
```

This all works because your top-level arrays are numerically-indexed.

Comment: Just what I was looking for. Gotta wait a few minutes before I can accept. Thank you.